# Could not find a model with id

Tags: angular, arangodb, loopback, angular2-nativescript

I can successfully create an object in ArangoDB using `loopback-connector-arango`. But while updating the item, it will not get updating into database instead getting an error:

```
could not find a model with id.
```

What I have is:

list.component.ts

```
updateGrocery(id) {

    this.listModel.name = this.groceryEdit.name;
    this.listService.updateItems(id, this.listModel)
        .subscribe(
        () => {
            this.store.dispatch(this.heroActions.loadHeroes());
        }
        )
    };
```

list.service.ts

```
updateItems(id, list: ItemList) {
    return this.itemListApi.updateAttributes(id,
        {
            "name": list.name
        }
    );
};
```

I am using Angular2 and TypeScript to develop this app, this is in angular2seedadvanced app and loopbacksdk builder. How can i solve this issue? Any help will very helpful and highly appreciable.

Comment: Well it cant find the model with that id.. Does that id really exists in your db?

Comment: could you post your `listModel.ts` ?

Comment: yes that id exist in my db. adding new item will working perfectly to this model

Comment: my listModel.ts is loopback model